# How to add a display: block to a navigation bar without breaking display: inline?

Tags: navigation, nav, css

I'm struggling with getting my navigation bar working, everything looks but, but I would like the entire block area around the text to be clickable as opposed to just the text itself.

It all looks good, but when I add display: block to the 'a' element, the inline breaks and I get a list of nav items.

Hopefully someone can help me out, it seems pretty easy but I've been struggling with it for a couple days.

ie, doing this breaks it:

```
nav li a{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zvHa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some padding to your anchors so they are wider and more clickable.

For example:

```
nav li a{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, ok, that was super easy. I guess I just had all my padding on the li and not the link.

Here's the updated fiddle in case someone else has the same issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/9zvHa/4/